# typescript disallow empty string

Tags: typescript

I would like to define a property on a TS class that will accept any string but not an empty string (''). Is there a way to do this?

Something like this:

```
class Foo {
   id: string & Not<''>
}

const bar = new Foo
bar.id = '' // ts compile error
bar.id = 'whatever string you want' // ts compile allowed
```

or

```
type nonEmptyString = Exclude<string, ''>
const something1: nonEmptyString = '' // ts compile error
const something: nonEmptyString = 'f' // ts compile allowed
const something2: nonEmptyString = '1' // ts compile allowed
```

Comment: That post has to do with passing an empty string into a function and doesn't have anything to do with classes.

Comment: Typescript does not have "not" types, sadly. You can use conditional types that can be used in functions (`T extends '' ? never : T` or something) . But I'm reasonably certain that its not possible to have the last three lines of your code work like you expect them to.

Comment: I really don't understand why they didn't allow this to work:
`type nonEmptyString = Exclude<string, ''>`